# вывод http запроса в json

Tags: javascript, json

Прошу помощи, есть запрос в формате https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=YOUR_API_KEY
как вывести "отдачу" в json?
заранее благодарен

Comment: Отдача уже в json

Comment: Вам нужно сохранить в файл?

Comment: нет я пытаюсь отобразить массив на странице, гуглю как сделать json encode from url

Comment: @KuminovLev Вы этот запрос как делаете? с помощю `ajax` или `PHP CURL`? это нам нужно узнать

Comment: да, простите въехал, отдача в json. как теперь вывести это на сайте....

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Простите все что у меня есть это URL)) я же говорю я нуб).

Comment: @KuminovLev Откуда вы отправляете запрос? Не с браузера?

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот пример запроса на этот `url` с помощю `ajax`

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=YOUR_API_KEY',
    success: function(data) {
        //Здесь в `data` будет ваш `json` можете работать с ним как хотите
    },
    error: function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Если подробный код дадите вашей страницы поменяю ответ и сделаю подробный пример вывода данных.

Comment: вот URL https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJZfvsc5bP20YRPc9hI1MCGm4&key=AIzaSyB-0-eIGH0K74MRmEsdNY9ND1cgk1LQnmo Спасибо что помогаете, ребята!

Comment: @KuminovLev почти разобрался, можете поменять вопрос и дать картинку для примера показа данных на странице?

Comment: дать картинку не смогу, так как в рунете этого нет, многие в англоязычном сегменте пишут, что отзывы из гугл можно получить только с использованием google API. не понял в части замены вопроса

Comment: @KuminovLev я данные получаю с помощью `ajax` а что потом мне с ними делать? у вас на странице как оно должно отобразиться?

Comment: я не знаю как оно отобразиться, может так как пример: https://wordimpress.com/assets/google-places-reviews-widget-themes-3-180x180.jpg

Comment: Лучше вам сделать так как здесь в доке написано https://developers.google.com/places/?hl=ru

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял вы хотите на карте `google` вывести места которые вам нужно.

Вот пример кода по вашему ՝api key՝.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place details</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
        
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 53.9, lng: 27.56667},
          zoom: 5
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

        service.getDetails({
          placeId: 'ChIJZfvsc5bP20YRPc9hI1MCGm4'
        }, function(place, status) {
          if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: place.geometry.location
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
                'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
                place.formatted_address + '</div>');
              infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB-0-eIGH0K74MRmEsdNY9ND1cgk1LQnmo&libraries=places&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Подробную инструкцию можете прочитать [здесь](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id?hl=ru).